# Databases - call certain table results on different pages

Tags: php, html, mysql, datatables, mysql-workbench

I have two databases, which I would like to somehow connect so that the results of each company were shown to a separate page. So that data table company are displayed, but categorized by table categories.

```sql
create table company (
   id int not null auto_increment primary key,
   name varchar (50) NOT NULL,
   address varchar (25) NOT NULL,
   city varchar (25) NOT NULL,
   state varchar (2) NOT NULL,
   email varchar (255) NOT NULL,
   categories int
) engine = innodb


create table categories (
   id int not null auto_increment primary key,
   name varchar (50) NOT NULL
) engine = innodb;

insert into categories (name)
values ('Computer Company');
insert into categories (name)
values ('Mechanical Company');
```

So from the base call in a particular category (on php page, the results) but only the results of a particular company. Is it possible somehow by id?

Comment: Do you have two separate databases, with two separate sets of tables for each company?

Comment: No, all companies goes to one database, maybe if I put in database companies category that people choose by select... and then somehow by that display on page...

Comment: You'll let them select a Category, and then you'll use that in a SQL where clause, something like Select... from Company where categories=?
Note: You are using a plural, but I assume each Company is in a single Category only.